# Windows service not working (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-services

I'm creating my first Windows service and it compiles and the installation process is successful and I can start it but it doesn't seem to do any of the tasks I program it to carry out. The following is my main class:

```
public partial class Service : ServiceBase
{
    private Timer timer = new Timer(1000);

    public Service()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter("file.txt", true))
        {
            streamWriter.WriteLine("Service");
        }

        this.timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;

        this.timer.Start();
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter("file.txt", true))
        {
            streamWriter.WriteLine("OnTimedEvent");
        }
    }
}
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Do you get any exceptions when debugging?

Comment: Ok, here is just my thoughts about you problem. You start it, but don't see `file.txt` at service folder, so you decided that it does not work. But default working directory is `%WinDir%\System32`, that's where you file is

Comment: (Just tested, on x64 it writes into SYSWOW64)

Comment: Why isn't the default working directory the same as the one where the executable is?

Comment: i know this has little to do with your question, but if I may make a suggestion, use Topshelf to create your services. No installer package needed and it makes it WAY easier to debug (like a console program, cause that's essentially what it is when you use Topshelf) http://topshelf-project.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realise that the default working directory for my Windows service is `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`. I just made the assumption that it was the `bin\Release` directory where my executable is located.